# Number of sunday, monday, etc before current date in current month using Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, days

I have one date field inside table, and i want to find the number of sunday's before current date in current month using mysql.

How can i get the number of sunday, monday, etc before current date in current month ?

Comment: WHat have you attempted?

Comment: What is relation of date field with the question??

Comment: Here All Date and Time Related Function Check This and Try Your Self

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-date-time-functions.htm

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry i m new in this, dont know more about this so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the no of Sundays in current month and your date column is less than to current date by using `SUM` with expression `DAYNAME(created) ='sunday'` ,using sum with expression will result in a boolean 0 or 1,also make sure you have stored the standard date object in your date field in my case i have used the name as created, and in where clause i have compared the date column with current month dates

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(DAYNAME(created) ='Sunday'),0) `sundays`
FROM `table`
WHERE  created > LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
 AND   created < CURRENT_DATE()
```

**After question is edited** you can also count no. days by their name as below for a period from month starting  to current date

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(DAYNAME(created) ='Sunday'),0) `sundays`,
IFNULL(SUM(DAYNAME(created) ='Monday'),0) `mondays`,
IFNULL(SUM(DAYNAME(created) ='Tuesday'),0) `tuesdays`,
IFNULL(SUM(DAYNAME(created) ='Wednesday'),0) `wednesdays`,
IFNULL(SUM(DAYNAME(created) ='Thursday'),0) `thursdays`,
IFNULL(SUM(DAYNAME(created) ='Friday'),0) `fridays`,
IFNULL(SUM(DAYNAME(created) ='Saturday'),0) `saturdays`
FROM `table`
WHERE  created > LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
AND   created < CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Thanks for help, please give the up to my question  .